Periodic function in terms of localized function
I have a periodic function $n(x)$ such that
$$n(x)= n(x+L),$$
where $L$ is the periodicity.
Now, there is a statement that says "any periodic function $n$ can be written—in a non-unique way—as the superposition of a localized function $n_\text{loc}$ and of its periodic replicas" and one can write
$$n(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} n_{\text{loc}}(x - kL).$$
I am not able to understand this statement and how it leads to final result for $n(x)$! Could this be explained to me?

This is more of a math question as opposed to a physics question, so it belongs on [math.se]. That said, one way to do it is to just define $n_{\textrm{loc}}$ as a piece of $n(x)$ defined between $[0,L]$, i.e., $$n_{\textrm{loc}} = \begin{cases}n(x) & 0\leq x\leq L \0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases},.$$ Then summing translates of that windowed function will give you $n(x)$ back exactly.

Trig-Fourier transform n(x), and then define your $n_{loc}$ to be that Fourier series evaluated between 0 and L.
